# query sort records randomly

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am showing in my view all the users of my user table, in the table there is a field called "order" in which I assign a number to the first 200 records so that these users who had the value in the "order" field are will show first that those who had null in that field.

Is it possible that those first 200 users can show them first and randomly?

this is my query:

```
@users = User.includes(:plan).with_avatar



@users = @users.order( '`order` DESC, sponsor DESC, id DESC' ) 
@users = @users.paginate(page: page).per_page(18)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible that those first 200 users can show them first and randomly?

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN order <= 200
              THEN RAND()
              ELSE order
              END
```

Comment: thanks for answer. I am testing it and if it works, the problem is that it is not working with the first order, which first places all the records that had a value in the "order" field

Comment: with this one @users = @users.order( '`order` DESC, sponsor DESC, id DESC' )

Comment: *the problem is that it is not working with the first order, which first places all the records that had a value in the "order" field* I give the solution to the question only. If you need the records with NULL values to be last additionally then place `order IS NULL` sorting level before.

Comment: "order IS NULL" is placed in a .order before?

Comment: @jeff ``ORDER BY `order` IS NULL, CASE WHEN `order` <= 200  THEN RAND() ELSE `order` END``

Comment: thanks. In the case of those with order = 0, could I also exclude them at the end with the values that have order = null?

Comment: @jeff Well, this is elementary... replace ``BY `order` IS NULL`` with ``BY `order` != 0 DESC`` (or `>` if `order` is defined as UNSIGNED).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend:

```
order by (case when order is not null) desc,
         rand()
```